# Locking does not work with SVN (64 bit)

Tags: windows-7, svn, 64-bit, tortoisesvn, locking

We are using Subversion to manage a big project.

Everyone normally has to lock a file before they can modify it.

There are several new new machines with Windows 7, SVN (64 bit) and this directive in the config file:

```
 ** = svn:needs-lock=true
 *.* = svn:needs-lock=true*
```

If a user with one of these new machine creates a new file, the file will remain editable at all times even without requiring a lock. And when users update it without using a lock, it then causes a conflict.

Answer (score 0):

Eek.  Merge, don't lock; this ain't CVS.

Likely the config file isn't actually being applied for whatever reason - where is this file located?  You'll also need to make sure that `enable-auto-props` is set somewhere in the config.

To ensure that all your files have that property set regardless of client misconfiguration, add a pre-commit hook that rejects the commit if it's not present.